# IIS 6 error with NETWORK SERVICE identity

Tags: iis-6

I have a rarelly situation on IIS6.
I have 1 APP-Pool that not working with the identity: NETWORK SERVICE.
Only work with Identity Local System, but use this is danger (height permission level).
The web page asp.net open, but the application asp.net try to connect the database follow the next error:

```
Event Type: Information Event Source:   ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0 Event Category: Web Event  Event ID:    1314 Date:      7/6/2013 Time:      12:05:04 PM User:       N/A Computer:   WWW Description: Event code: 4011  Event message: An unhandled access exception has occurred.  Event time: 7/6/2013 12:05:04 PM  Event time (UTC): 7/6/2013 4:05:04 PM  Event ID: aa4f0c3196864dc391467c9492a1b8a3  Event sequence: 10  Event occurrence: 1  Event detail code: 0    Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1598207490/Root-4-130176002992160068 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\Inetpub\WebVarios\WebLocutorios\ 
    Machine name: WWW    Process information: 
    Process ID: 1572 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE    Request information: 
    Request URL: http://casetas.cuentacentral.com/ajax/logincenter.aspx 
    Request path: /ajax/logincenter.aspx 
    User host address: 190.135.0.26 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE    Custom event details: 

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely NETWORK SERVICE user doesn't have sufficient access to the database.
Try disabling any custom error handlers (like customErrors in web.config) and review the output. Or you may attach a VS debugger to w3wp.exe process and see exceptions before they're handled.

Comment: I received error 404, but the resource exist when use identity: Local System.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Comment: What about file system permissions for Network Service user? Does it have access to the requested file?